# DataTable jQuery plugin not showing anything

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I've been trying to get DataTable to work with my MVC 5 project, but I've had no luck. No CSS is showing on the headers of the columns to even show a hint of DataTable working. I've been working on this for about two days now with no success. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
@model IEnumerable<BlahBlahBlah.Models.tbl_Reg_User>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@section Scripts{
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.3/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#thetable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
}

<body>
<h2>User List</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckBoxAction", "User"))
{
    <input type="submit" name="deactivateButton" value="Deactivate Selected Users" onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("CheckBoxAction", "User")'" />
    <input type="submit" name="activateButton" value="Activate Selected Users" onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("CheckBoxAction", "User")'" />
    <table id="thetable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Select Users
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.department)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
                </th>

                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ids" id="ids" value="@item.ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                        @if (item.suspended)
                        {
                            @Html.ActionLink("Activate", "Activate", new { id = item.ID })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.ActionLink("Deactivate", "Deactivate", new { id = item.ID })
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="deactivateButton" value="Deactivate Selected Users" onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("CheckBoxAction", "User")'" />
    <input type="submit" name="activateButton" value="Activate Selected Users" onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("CheckBoxAction", "User")'" />
}

@*<input type="button" value="Deactivate" onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("CheckBoxDeactivate", "User")'" />
    <input type="button" value="Activate" onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("CheckBoxActivate", "User")'" />*@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if all the .css and .js file are present at the path mentioned in the View.